# Error 500 al intentar conexion FTP en PHP

Tags: php, ftp, appserv

Estoy intentando realizar una conexión de base de datos local y a ftp. 
Anteriormente usando Xampp funcionaba correctamente, pero debido a un error de un compañero, ahora estamos usando AppServ. 
Acá es cuando inicia el problema, dado que la conexion LOCAL funciona correctamente, pero al momento de realizar la conexión FTP, todo lleva a error 500. Ejemplos a continuacion (datos censurados)

```
//Conexion Local
$usuario = "root";
$password = "password";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "basedatos";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
$db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos) or die("Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
```

Hasta acá todo bien, pero al momento de agregarle la conexion FTP, todo se cae. Salta error 500.

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.miftp.cl";
$ftp_user_name = "username";
$ftp_user_pass = 'password';
$destination_file = "/file/";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {  
    echo "¡La conexión FTP ha fallado!";
    echo "Se intentó conectar al $ftp_server por el usuario $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Conexión a $ftp_server realizada con éxito, por el usuario $ftp_user_name";
}
```

**Que es lo que está fallando acá ?**

--- EDIT1
Me estoy dando cuenta que el erro salta desde el uso de ftp_connect().

Comment: El servidor FTP acepta conexiones externas? Esta puesto que escuche en el puerto 21, que es el que ftp_connect indica por defecto?

Comment: Si, nos conectamos desde varios lados, y repito. Este mismo codigo funcionaba hace 2 dias usando xampp en vez de appserv

Comment: Tenéis algún archivo de log que pueda aclararlos algo? Aparentemente es que no se admite la conexión hacia ese FTP. Algún apache_log, access_log?

Comment: Aparentemente ftp_connect te está devolviendo null (cosa que en principio puede ser correcta por algún problema de conexión) luego el ftp_login necesita un objeto connection para su primer parámetro, pero es un null (ahí es donde seguramente te de el 500, como un error de código)

Comment: @Jakala buscare esos logs a ver que dicen. Y como puedo revisar lo 2do que me mencionas ?

Comment: @Jakala aca parece haber algo. `[Fri Oct 23 10:25:51.947454 2020] [php7:warn] [pid 4608:tid 1152] [client ::1:60834] PHP Warning:  Unterminated comment starting line 21 in C:\\AppServ\\www\\script\\conexion.php on line 21
[Fri Oct 23 10:25:51.958453 2020] [php7:error] [pid 4608:tid 1152] [client ::1:60834] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ftp_connect() in C:\\AppServ\\www\\script\\conexion.php:18\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\AppServ\\www\\script\\conexion.php on line 18`

Comment: @Jakala Gracias por la ayuda, encontre la solución, añadiré la respuesta ahora mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como pude darme cuenta, el error se daba desde que se hacía el uso de la función `ftp_connect()`.
Todo esto indica que el error no es a nivel de codigo, sino a nivel de soporte FTP.
Gracias a la ayuda de Jakala, al revisar los logs de error ubicados en `AppServ\Apache24\logs`, 
se da cuenta del problema :

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ftp_connect()
```

Esto quiere decir que FTP no esta habilitado actualmente. 
Para revisar el estado FTP se puede usar el siguiente comando en CMD.

```
php --ri ftp
```

Lo cual nos dirá si FTP esta habilitado o no.
En caso de no estarlo, debemos dirigirnos al archivo `php.ini` de nuestra aplicación.
En mi caso es: `AppServ\php7\php.ini`
Dentro de este archivo, debemos agregar la siguiente linea (en cualquier parte del archivo)

```
extension=php_ftp.dll
```

Luego de esto, procedemos a reinicar nuestro servicio de apache
**y finalmente habremos solucionado el problema.**

Comment: Uff.. no había caído tampoco en esa... Que podía faltarte la librería de FTP. Enhorabuena por encontrar el fallo. Me lo apunto para futuras 

Comment: Todo gracias a ti, yo tampoco hubiera revisado los logs por mi cuenta.